# Reactivity of 1-bromo-4-tert-butylcyclohexane isomers with methanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, isomers, elimination

> 1. (1*s*,4*s*)-1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane (**1**) and (1*r*,4*r*)-1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane (**2**) are heated (E2) with $\ce{NaOCH3}/\ce{CH3OH}.$ Which isomer will react faster?
>    [image: 1: (1s,4s)-1-bromo-4-tert-butylcyclohexane; 2: (1r,4r)-1-bromo-4-tert-butylcyclohexane]
> 2. What will change when $\ce{CH3OH}$ without the strong base is used?

I drew chair conformation of both with $\ce{Br}$ in axial position, so it can undergo E2. In **1** I got $\ce{^tBu}$ in *axial* position, in **2** I got $\ce{^tBu}$ in *equatorial* position.

Would it be correct to say that because **2** is more stable due to bulky group in equatorial position, it would react slower in E2?

For the second part of the question I suggested S<sub>N</sub>1. But then how would I know which would be faster in this case, since the $\ce{Br}$ does not have to be axial?

Comment: Which group has the greater A-value? Is it equatorial or axial? What are the geometrical requirements for an E2 elimination? Now you have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are right on the part of E2, **2** will react slower. The reactivity of SN1 follows the same order - the carbocations are same but in **1** due to $\ce{Br}$ being on the axial position, the $\ce{C-Br}$ bond will dissociate easily to form the carbocation and so **1** reacts faster than **2**.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

These are geometric isomers, cis-trans compounds so the RS nomenclature is not appropriate. If they were mirror images they would have identical reaction rates in an achiral system

The general idea is that a bulky group such as t-butyl is almost always equatorial. The 1,4-trans has both groups equatorial so is most likely the lower energy reactant [higher transition E] by a SN1-E1 mechanism since the cis and trans carbonium ion are the same. It is a bit different for E2 since the cis is set up for the lower energy anti transition state and is the higher energy molecule. What I am having trouble visualizing is the reaction of the carbonium ion in an SN1 reaction and the cis-trans product ratio in the ether. Models might help here.

Comment: The CIP rules assign lower case r/s descriptors to these two achiral, stereoisomers. See examples [here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/achiral.html).

Comment: I didn't know this and after checking your link am thoroughly confused. I learned this years ago when the rules were in their infancy and obviously didn't learn enough. I fail to see why this rates a down vote perhaps a comment. I think my answer should help the questioner evaluate the energetics of the reaction of the two isomers.

Comment: It wasn't my down vote. CIP rules have evolved over time. I think the link is quite explicit as to how the assignments are made. This [link](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/CIP%20rules%20NEW.html) goes through the CIP rules step-by-step. Your explanation for the E2 elimination, cis faster than trans, is fine.